# Synchronize Subversion trunk with branches

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, merge

I'm working in a small team (3 devs in total). We are using Eclipse and Subclipse plugin for managing SVN repository. Project we are working on is quite complex (20 modules, each in form of a separate project). From beginning we have used simplest possible SVN structure where everything is in trunk. When time comes to deploy *certain* functionalities to the production I (being some sort of deploy manager) do this:

1. I have a separate workspace on my disk where I hold the production code. I open that workspace in separate Eclipse instance.
2. I perform synchronization (team -> synchronize) of all modules against the trunk (remember - everything is in the trunk, no branches).
3. I pick each and every changed file (or sometimes only few lines concerning the feature I want deployed!) manually and save local copy of the "production" workspace.
4. I build the project and prepare the deploy.

So basically our testing code everyone is working on is in the repo, production workspace is on my disk only. We are keeping all in trunk because 4 years ago we tried SVN branches and merges Things soon went so bad we barely cleaned our project from junk and decided never to use SVN branch / merge again.

Now, with current setup the problem is that only I am the one able to prepare deploy to production (only my disk has production workspace). I was thinking about giving SVN branching another chance - I created separate branch with production code. The problem I'm having now is that when I try to merge testing SVN branch into production SVN branch I can't any more control which code I want merged and which I don't - "merge" command merges everything!

Is there a way with Eclipse and Subclipse to "synchronize" two branches and "cherry-pick" only lines or classes I currently want? Sometimes out of 90 or 100 merged classes I want just 12 complete and few lines of code from few other classes... It would be easier to choose what's going in than revert what's not needed

P.S. we are not using Git as after years of SVNing Git seems very confusing, seems horrible for handling conflicts (and we have them, a lot!) and seems unable to work on "per file" level. Our team is small, code can be accessed and worked on from the office only. Git seems like an overkill.